# Create android native feature using Bayeux Protocol

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cometd, bayeux

I am trying to create an Android project and get the Bayeux Java Client library
working for it. I have the cometd library imported in my eclipse and I also added
the projects to the build path of my project.

My project builds fine, but on execution, I keep getting the NoClassDefFound error.
I am not sure, how to set my project up.

Are there any examples that I can refer to?

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: Is the library getting packaged into your `apk` by the Android build?

Comment: I think the library is, but the indirect dependencies are not getting packaged. Is there a way to be sure about it?

Comment: Are you building by hand? Have you tried Maven?

Answer (score 0):

I do the same thing and musst add some Other third party libraries. Check the NoClassDef Exception which class is needed and wasn't found. I Google the required class and add it to my libs folder. If i remember right it were some jetty client libs (3 or 4).